# Decorator to override save to write in Multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-models, decorator, python-decorators

I am planning to have models in our application to write into two databases. I wanted to write a decorator to use it for all models.  I am using the below code

```
class save_multi_db(models.Model):
    def __call__(self, cls):
        class Wrapped(cls):
            def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                redis_connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool=settings.MAPPING_REDIS_POOL)
                if int(redis_connection.get('write_to_db')):
                     super(cls, self).save(using='prod')
                     super(cls, self).save(using='default')
                else:
                     return cls.save()
        return Wrapped
```

I have classes like below

```
@save_multi_db()
class ModelA(models.Model):
    #model A 

class MobelB(ModelA):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'name'
```

This is perfectly working fine if I am using the decorator to a single model. But in the same models.py if I use the decorator on another model. I am getting the below error

```
(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Wrapped', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

Comment: I think it is rather weird to patch this at the model level, since typically a model is invariant of the databases that are used. You probably better implement *database routing*.

Comment: See for example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example

Comment: At first sight, it looks to me that you constructed *mutliple* classes all with the same name, and therefore Django get confused. Furthermore this `Wrapped` will probably fail in case it is already wrapped once.

Comment: I want it to have to write both the databases for sometime

Comment: I didn't get ,what you mean by the same name ? ModelA, ModelB(ModelA), ModelC. All are seperate model classes

Comment: yes, but if they get out of the decorator, then these are no longer really `ModelA`, and `ModelB` classes, you assigned these to a *variable* named `ModelA`, but check the `__name__`., it is **not** `ModelA`, it is all `Wrapped`.

Comment: Basically it is throwing this error      `RuntimeWarning: Model "transactions.wrapped'" was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models. `

Comment: exactly, since all models have as `modelA.__name__='Wrapped'`, and so Django got confused. According to `Django` it has *already* loaded that model.

Comment: Yes, right. It is actually becoming  `Wrapped` . Is there any way out? where can I have a decorator to override save to write to two databases ?

Comment: well like said before, the model layer is not the good place to do database routing. `.save(..)` is not always called. For example `ModelA.objects.update(foo=F('bar'))` will bypass the `.save(..)` anyway. So you probably better try to implement a database router.

Comment: With database router. How can we configure to write on two databases or single based on a redis key

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to solve the problem by overriding `Model.save()`, dont use a class decorator, use an abstract base class instead and override `save()` there:

```
class Multisave(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, *kw):
        # your code here

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ModelA(Multisave):
   # ...
```

but as Willem Van Onsem mentions, this will not work as expected for operations that bypass `Model.save()` so using a database router is certainly a much safer solution.

Comment: Can we write to two databases using DB router based on the config ?